# snapcraft make plugin change directory?

Tags: snap

I'm pulling a project off github that has multiple src folders for different instances (for different target architectures) in subfolders.  It builds with make when run in the instance subfolder you want.

How do I get snapcraft to run make in the correct directory (I can't only pull down that directory as there are common src files at the top level too)

Current yaml:

```
parts:
    base:
        plugin: make
            source: git://github.com/myproject.git
```

Answer (score 3):

Good question.

While you won't be able to do architecture detection within the YAML, you can tell the plugins to use a subdirectory of the source rather than the root. So as long as you're okay changing that subdirectory by hand depending on the architecture for which you're building, you're good.

Let's assume the layout of the project you're cloning looks like this:

```
/:
    subdir1:
        Makefile
    subdir2:
        Makefile
```

Let's also assume that you're only interested in building `subdir1`. Here's a snippet from `snapcraft help sources`:

> - source-subdir:
>
>   (string)
>
>   A source directory within a repository or tarfile to enter and build
>     from.

So you can Snapcraft what you want with YAML like this:

```
parts:
    base:
        plugin: make
        source: git://github.com/myproject.git
        source-type: git
        source-subdir: subdir1
```

That will cause `make`/`make install` to be run from subdir1. Note that this applies to any plugin that supports the `source` options.

EDIT:

Indeed, as sergiusens points out in the comments, `snapcraft help make` is useful to read, and points out another potential answer here:

```
parts:
    base:
        plugin: make
        source: git://github.com/myproject.git
        source-type: git
        makefile: subdir1/Makefile
```

That causes `make`/`make install` to be called with `-f subdir1/Makefile`

Comment: How about also mentioning the `-f` syntax and `snapcraft help make`?

Comment: Thanks!

Now make runs but it appears that both options still run it from an external directory  - I get errors like 

    Makefile:2: ../py/mkenvironment.mk: No such file or directory

Comment: @r4space you probably hit [bug #1549676](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapcraft/+bug/1549676), which has been fixed in 1.1.0 and will be released soon for 2.x